# Change table index to vector index MAPLE

Tags: arrays, vector, indexing, maple

I have a simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out because I am new to Maple.

```
 for i from 1 to 1 do
 for k from 1 to 4 do
 function_table[i][k] := 2*y[i][k]:
 function_vector[k]  := function_table[i][k]:
 od: od:
 print(function_vector):
```

output from print is

```
 table([1 = 2*y[1][1], 2 = 2*y[1][2], 3 = 2*y[1][3], 4 = 2*y[1][4]])
```

Now what I want to do is take function_vector, and remove the "table index" [1] so I get.

```
for k from 1 to 4 do
function_vector[k]  := 2*y[k]:
od:
print(function_vector):

table([1 = 2*y[1], 2 = 2*y[2], 3 = 2*y[3], 4 = 2*y[4]])
```

Basically I have the first expression, and I want to convert it to the second example I gave. For example, is there a command or a short way to make `y[1][1]` into `y[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, that works for your given example at least...

```
for i from 1 to 1 do
  for k from 1 to 4 do
    function_table[i][k] := 2*y[i][k]:
    function_vector[k]  := function_table[i][k]:
  end do;
end do:
print(function_vector):

    table([1 = 2 y[1][1], 2 = 2 y[1][2], 3 = 2 y[1][3], 4 = 2 y[1][4]])


for x in [indices(function_vector,nolist)] do
  new_vector[x]:=subsindets(function_vector[x],indexed,
                            u->op(0,op(0,u))[op(1,u)]);
end do:
print(new_vector);

    table([1 = 2 y[1], 2 = 2 y[2], 3 = 2 y[3], 4 = 2 y[4]])
```